# Read number from application.yml file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**step 1:**

I wanted to read the configuration file on Spring for minutesو Like the image below:

[image]

I used this code:

```
Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
log.info("output number:", environment.getProperty("shafagh.job.msg.cron"));
```

Output:

```
output number: 0 0/55 8-13
```

But this whole line is back, I just want to return a number **(0/55)**

**step 2:**

convert **0/55** to time or int ?

Comment: Why? You should not have to do that.

Comment: Because I want to retrieve this time

Comment: luk2302  - Do you suggest a better deal?

Comment: Don't want to be offending, but what exactly does it help you getting "0/55"? And what rule set will you apply to convert it to an "int" or a "time" value? I guess we cannot follow you because we have no idea what you really want to solve...

Answer (score 1):

OK, for **step 1**, just parse the string. There are many possible ways, but i think this one is sufficient:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cron = "0 0/55 8-13 ? * SAT,SUN,MON,TUE,WED";
    String[] parts = cron.split("\\s");
    System.out.println("Wanted part is: " + parts[1]); // "0/55"
}
```

For **step 2**, you will need to understand what this expression really means and how you can represent that in Java. I personally have no idea what you really need from that part (just the frequency? the offset? both of them?) so I cannot answer that part. Do you know why you want this to be converted into another type than string?

Comment: Marcus K. thank you
with the method "step 1", "step2" was solved